# Set a document's field to an array of ObjectIDs matching a query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Say I have a Mongo collection with some documents:

```
{ _id: ObjectId('idOfA'),
  name: 'a', type: 'vowel' },
{ _id: ObjectId('idOfB'),
  name: 'b', type: 'consonant' },
{ _id: ObjectId('idOfC'),
  name: 'c', type: 'consonant },
...
```

Now let's say I have another Document,

```
fav = {
  name: 'my favourite letters',
  letters: []
}
```

and that I also have an array `['a', 'c']`.

Is there a single-query way to update `fav` such that it is

```
{
  name: my favourite letters',
  letters: [
    ObjectId('idOfA'),
    ObjectId('idOfC')
  ]
}
```

?

I am using Mongoose, but happy for raw Mongo queries that do similar. I am envisioning something like (pseudo-mongo, don't laugh)

```
fav.set('letters', { $map: {
    input: {$find : ObjectID in ['a','c']},
    as: 'letterDoc',
    in: '$$letterDoc._id'
}});
```

Comment: No, one query is not possible. Two queries at best.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the direct answer to my question, I'd accept it if I could :)

Answer (score 0):

With "node.js" the bottom line here is that you **need** to implement a "callback" or "promise" to resolve the asynchronous response from the prior query operation. This is what is basically required as you first need to "query" for the items you want from the other collection before "adding" those items to your related object.

Here is an example of [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) which can be used to "pass in" the result of a prior query to the arguments of another:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var letterSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  type: { type: String, enum: ['consonant','vowel'] }
});


var favoriteSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  letters: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Letter' }]
});

var Letter = mongoose.model( 'Letter', letterSchema ),
    Favorite = mongoose.model( 'Favorite', favoriteSchema );

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

mongoose.set("debug",true);

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      async.each([Letter,Favorite],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      async.each(
        [
          { "name": "a", "type": "vowel" },
          { "name": "b", "type": "consonant" },
          { "name": "c", "type": "consonant" }
        ],
        function(letter,callback) {
          Letter.create(letter,callback);
        },
        callback
      );
    },
    function(callback) {
      Favorite.create({ "name": "mine" },callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      async.waterfall(
        [
          function(callback) {
            Letter.find({ "name": { "$in": ["a","c"] } },callback);
          },
          function(letters,callback) {
            Favorite.findOneAndUpdate(
              { "name": "mine" },
              { "$push": { "letters": { "$each": letters } } },
              { "new": true },
              callback
            );
          }
        ],
        callback
      )
    },
    function(callback) {
      Favorite.find().populate('letters').exec(function(err,docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        callback(err)
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Which gives nice output like:

```js
[ { _id: 55eed7dfc7b23b7c4838903b,
    name: 'mine',
    __v: 0,
    letters:
     [ { _id: 55eed7dfc7b23b7c48389038,
         name: 'a',
         type: 'vowel',
         __v: 0 },
       { _id: 55eed7dfc7b23b7c4838903a,
         name: 'c',
         type: 'consonant',
         __v: 0 } ] } ]
```

Note the line in the listing there:

```js
 { "$push": { "letters": { "$each": letters } } }
```

As within the [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) method used, the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator will "atomically" append to the array in the document already in place, and the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier allows this to accept an "array" of arguments as opposed to a single object to append.

Mongoose also handles the "translation" of the "objects" returned from the prior `.find()` to just inserting the `_id` values required by the schema. Also the whole `async.waterfall` process, passes in the returned value from the prior result callback into the next stage in the function.

That "last" is basically "nicer" than writing this:

```js
Letter.find({ "name": { "$in": ["a","c"] } },function(err,docs) {
    Favourite.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "name": "mine" },
        { "$push": { "letters": { "$each": letters } } },
        { "new": true },
        function(err,result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    );
});
```

Where the "indent creep" is just nasty.

So the "bottom line" again, is that you need to `.find()` the results first and then "use" those results within your "update" operation to append to the array. There are various ways to do this, but using "atomic" `$push` is your best option for performance and reliability.

Aside from general "practicality" of creating a collection to store "alphabet" details and also using `ObjectId` as opposed to the natural "key" from the alphabet letter itself as something to link to then that is the basic process of how to handle this.

Comment: That's a shame, I had hoped Mongo could do this internally, like it can for populating full collections from from the results of aggregations. Also, your code looks quite a bit more verbose than the workaround I came up with -- is there a reason you wouldn't use native promises, map()s, and then()s?
Thanks for the detailed response. :)

Comment: @Jarrad The only shame here is your lack of understanding. MongoDB does "nothing interally" such as "populating collections". It is completely schemaless and basically "does nothing but store" as by design. This is a "good thing". As for "workaround you came up with", it just is plain not possible to do anything without returning the results from a prior query in the format asked in your question. Using promises or callbacks has nothing to do with it. You simply need to return the result from the queried collection in order to use those results in the next statement.

Comment: @Jarrad The best 'workaround' or in fact "best practice" is not not do something as silly as try to store in "alphabet" in a collection at all, and simply instantiate something basically constant in memory. Just trying to show you how it can be done with the methods you described. I opened with "basically a very silly way to approach this".

Comment: I'm not holding the alphabet (or indeed any such constant data) in Mongo, that is a stupidly simplified example to demonstrate the functionality I am after. And I am a bit confused as to why they have implemented a quite powerful Aggregations framework if Mongo does "nothing but store".

Comment: @Jarrad I think you need to sit back and accept that the answer to your question is not what you conceive it to be but instead what is actually available to you. Queries to not send to the server and expand "inline" as that is called a "join" in principle, and something MongoDB does not do. It would be wiser to learn the lesson rather than sit around hoping for a non existant feature to emerge.